# How to manipulate JQuery to target one div and not another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Apologies if this question is a bit simple and been answered in one form or another before, but I'm new to JQuery and still adjusting to using the selectors and I was not sure what to search for to find the answer I needed.

I have two different selections of links. One of which I wish to apply some JQuery to, but not the rest of the page. My first div selector is as below, these are the links I wish to apply the JQuery to:

```
<div id="tabs-1">
   <a href='http://www.collectormania.com/'>Collectormania</a>
   <a href='http://www.game.co.uk/'>Game</a>
   <a href='http://www.lipsum.com/'>Ipsum Generator</a>
   <a href='http://www.netflix.com'>Netflix</a>
   <a href='http://www.pixel2life.com/'>Pixel2Life</a>
   <a href='http://www.port-vale.co.uk/'>Port Vale</a>
   <a href='http://www.roleplayer.me/'>Roleplayer</a>
   <a href='http://stackoverflow.com/'>Stack Overflow</a>
   <a href='http://www.themarauders.co.uk/'>The Marauders</a>
   <a href='http://www.torrentz.com/'>Torrentz</a>
   <a href='http://www.trueachievements.com/'>True Achievements</a>
</div>
```

And the group I don't wish to apply them to is:

```
<div id="social">
   <a href="#"><img src="images/social/deviantart.png" alt="DeviantArt"/></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="images/social/facebook.png" alt="Facebook"/></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="images/social/flickr.png" alt="Flickr"/></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="images/social/google+.png" alt="Google+"/></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="images/social/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn"/></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="images/social/tumblr.png" alt="Tumblr"/></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="images/social/twitter.png" alt="Twitter"/></a>
   <a href="#"><img src="images/social/youtube.png" alt="You Tube"/></a>
</div>
```

Finally the JQuery to modify is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a[href^='http']").each(function() {
        $(this).css({
            background: "url(http://g.etfv.co/" + this.href + ") left center no-repeat",
            "padding": "0px",
            "padding-bottom": "4px",
            "padding-left": "30px"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: How can I not apply the Query to the social div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of the links you want to select are going to be in that one div, a faster and more specific selector would be "#tabs-1 a" instead of "a[href^='http']". So, try:

```
$("#tabs-1 a").each(function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the div ID in the selector:

```
$("#tabs-1>a[href^='http']").each(function() {
    $(this).css({
        background: "url(http://g.etfv.co/" + this.href + ") left center no-repeat",
        "padding": "0px",
        "padding-bottom": "4px",
        "padding-left": "30px"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could go over id first

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#tabs-1 > a[href^="http"]').each(function() {
    $(this).css({
        background: "url(http://g.etfv.co/" + this.href + ") left center no-repeat",
        "padding": "0px",
        "padding-bottom": "4px",
        "padding-left": "30px"
    });
});
</script>
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/55z8Q/

and for the selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/